# Retrieve objects only containing a particular value in firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database structured roughly like this:

```
Firebase
  Bills
     BillID: "1"
        Name: "Date"
        Location: "Pizza Hut"
        userID: "aaaaaaaaa"
     BillID: "2"
        Name: "Party"
        Location: "Burger king"
        userID: "bbbbbbbbbb"
     BillID: "3"
        Name: "Birthday"
        Location: "MacDonalds"
        userID: "bbbbbbbbbb"
```

I can find bills by id fine, but I don't understand how I would go about find returning all bills that contain a specific usedID. So if I search for bills by userID: "bbbbbbbbbb" it would return Bills with id's 2,3. Equally a search for bills by userID: "aaaaaaaaa" would return Bills with id's 1.

Eventually the userId will become an array of userID's, but I want to understand the first part before I get to that.

Thanks for any help

Comment: try Database.database().reference().child("Bills").queryOrdered(byChild: "userID").queryEqual(toValue: userID)

Comment: Thanks! Havent tested it yet but would this also work if userID was an array of strings too?

Comment: I assume you would be putting that into for loop and getting individual userID and passing that for firebase?

Comment: So, many users can have many bills.  If i search for bills that contain a userID the query will return however many bills that contain that userID and the bills children.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be afraid of denormalizing your data and write several time the same piece of data. In your case you could, in parallel to your existing data structure, have another structure which is adapted to your querying needs, like:

```
Firebase
  Bills
    ....  (you existing structure)
  UserIDs
     aaaaaaaaa
        BillID: "1"
           Name: "Date"
           Location: "Pizza Hut"
     bbbbbbbbb
        BillID: "2"
           Name: "Party"
           Location: "Burger king"
       BillID: "3"
           Name: "Birthday"
           Location: "MacDonalds"
```

This is quite common in the NoSQL world. The storage is so cheap that it is not a problem to duplicate data in such a way it suits your needs for querying. In addition it will give better performances.